# Try catch input invalid type integer input

Tags: npm

I use swagger, now i want to catch input data.
My code:

> ```
> @GET
> @Path("/getById/{wId}")
> @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
> @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
> @ApiOperation(value = "Get warehouse by id", notes = "Get warehouse by id", response = Warehouse.class)
> @ApiResponses(value = { 
>         @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid Id supplied"),
>         @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Warehouse not found") })
> public Response getWarehouseById(
>         @ApiParam(value = "ID of warehouse to fetch", required = true) @PathParam("wId") int wId)
>         throws WebApplicationException {
>     Warehouse warehouse = warehouseService.findWarehouseByID(wId);
>     if(warehouse != null && warehouse.getWareHouseID() != 0){
>         String[] errorMessage = new String[]{};
>         String[] message = new String[]{Constants.SUCCESS};
>         Object[] rows = new Object[]{warehouse};
>         return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.SUCCESS,errorMessage,rows,message)).build(); 
>     }else{
>         String[] errorMessage = new String[]{Constants.NOT_FOUND};
>         String[] message = new String[]{};
>         Object[] rows = new Object[]{};
>         return Response.status(ApiResponseMessage.NOT_FOUND).entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.NOT_FOUND,errorMessage, rows, message)).build();
>     }
> }
> ```

If i input string value to int wId, i'll get result

```
Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'int': not a valid Integer value
```

Could you tell me how to fix? Tks all...